# Do any databases other than SAP ASE support key custodians?

Tags: security, transparent-data-encryption, encryption, sap-ase-16

[SAP Sybase ASE](https://www.sap.com/products/sybase-ase.html) supports the notion of a [key custodian](https://help.sap.com/viewer/3542b1cbbec34816b0b36cf19c760659/16.0.2.2/en-US/a7d5a3fdbc2b1014ace1b2a66212286b.html). This allows for a setup where the trust can be split between two roles: the database administrator and a key custodian. The database administrator has the privileges to create user accounts and give them privileges on tables and accounts, whereas the key custodian only has the ability to create and assigns encryption keys to users. Hence neither of these roles by themselves can create a full set of credentials that would allow access the data stored in the database. This capability is wonderful in low trust environments.

I get the sense that SAP ASE is no longer a priority at SAP. This might be totally wrong, and is only based on the fact that I am predominantly seeing HANA being pushed these days. I am therefore looking for other database systems that have an equivalent capability.
So far I haven't been able to find any database where it isn't the admin that in one way or another has the task of creating encryption keys as well.

Are there other database servers with an equivalent functionality that I have missed? I would really appreciate any guidance and tips!

Thank you!